# Hide function header in python

Tags: python, function

This may be a strange request but what I am trying to do is that the function header (especially the parameters) doesn't look like how it was defined in the first place.
For example the definition should be as follows:

```py
@HeaderChangingDecorator("a, b=None")
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    """A function."""
    return args[0]
```

but when calling it should look like this (e.g. in the IDEs preview):

```py
foo(a, b=None)
A function.
```

I know it is possible and I know that I have done it before but for the life of me I can't figure out how or what it was called.

Comment: For IDEs this is often done using docblock comments, not code.

Comment: With docblocks you can't change the appearance of the parameters, just the documentation. So thats not what I'm looking for.